# Como tratar resultados de uma query com PHP OO?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, aplicação-web

Estou criando um website simples, de fotografia, e eu estou fazendo todo o PHP orientado a objetos. Conheço PHP procedural, mas gostaria de misturar o PHP com o HTML o menos possível. Minha conexão e minha query estão sendo executadas perfeitamente, porém eu gostaria de saber como tratar o resultado da query da melhor maneira possível.

Minha função para a query:

```
function consultarDados($query){
    $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
    mysql_select_db($this->banco, $conexao);
    $rs = mysql_query($query, $conexao);
    return $rs;
    mysql_close($conexao);
}
```

E como eu estou tratando-a na página index.php:

```
include 'connectDB.php';
$conexao = new connectDb();
$retorno = $conexao->consultarDados('select * from slides');
    if(mysql_num_rows($retorno) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retorno)){
            echo $row ['imagem'];//esta parte eu fiz apenas para verificar se os resultados da query estão sendo obtidos de maneira correta.
        }
    }
```

Eu preciso inserir o resultado da query no nome das imagens desse pedaço do HTML:

```
<img src="img/slide_1.jpg"  class="img-slide ativa">
<img src="img/slide_2.jpg"  class="img-slide">
<img src="img/slide_3.jpg"  class="img-slide">
```

Obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Forma simples

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retorno)){
            echo '<img src="img/'.$row ['imagem'].'"  class="img-slide">';
        }
```

> Usando Template neste caso o Dwoo

você cria um template `dwoo`

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   {loop $items}
     <img src="img/{escape($item)}"  class="img-slide">
   {/loop}
  </body>
</html>
```

e cria o script php que irá criar o array e passar ao template:

```
<?php
include 'dwooAutoload.php';

try {
  $dwoo = new Dwoo();

  $tpl = new Dwoo_Template_File('tmpl/list.tpl');

  $data = new Dwoo_Data();
  $items = array();
  $items[] = array('item' => 'slide_1');
  $items[] = array('item' => 'slide_2');
  $items[] = array('item' => 'slide_3');
  $items[] = array('item' => 'slide_4');
  $data->assign('items', $items);

  // injeta os valores e exibe a pagina, note que o nome do indices são identicos as 
//variaveis dentro do template, o dwoo irá fazer a injeção paseado nos nomes identicos.
  $dwoo->output($tpl, $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();      
}
?>
```

Link para download do **Dwoo**: http://dwoo.org/

Link para tutorial aprofundado do **Dwoo**: [Tutorial aprofundado](http://devzone.zend.com/1746/building-template-driven-web-applications-with-dwoo-part-1/)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: @anuseranother Disponha.